# Restricts few categories from the pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used the '*Recent posts*' in Two pages and I need to restrict some posts with specific categories from those two pages. I have added the below code in the functions.php and Saved. But the expected result is not coming. 
Home page (*ID - 12*) and Poems Page (*ID - 8*) are those pages I have added the restriction 
772 and 152 are the category ID's of those I want to restrict from the mentioned pages.

```
function excludeCat($query) {
    $page = get_query_var('paged', 1);

    $exclude = [
        12 => '-772',
        8  => '-152'
    ];

    if ($query->is_home && isset($exclude[$page])) {
         $query->set('cat', $exclude[$page]);
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'excludeCat');
```

Please advise on the code

Comment: You need to pass id with comma seperated in set method like $query->set('cat', '-772,-152');. you can also refer the link i have attached here  : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Examples

Comment: @SohilChamadia Thanks for the reply.......I have added the code as in the provided link in the functions.php and still those categories are showing in the home page.....Then I have tried your second example to show only one category. That also was not working for me. All the categories were listing in the home page...What could be the issue in this case?>

Comment: can you please tell me what you have done to get "Recent posts" as well as please check the category ID you are passing is it correct?

Comment: @SohilChamadia For getting the latest posts on the home page, I have created a page then added the 'Recent Posts' widget in the page. Few categories of posts should not come on this page. That's why I am looking to restrict the specific category posts in the page

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the below code and write it in "functions.php" file.It may help you.

```
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'my_widget_posts_args');
function my_widget_posts_args($args) {
        return array(
            'cat' => array(-5,-4) // pass the term id of category which you want to exclude with prefix "-".
             );

}
```